# How to update events from SignalR in widget at the same time as event happens?

Tags: flutter, dart, signalr

How to poll the event if new data appeared in the event? I am using SinglR package to get data from websocket. It has way to wotk with events from websockets, but my problem is it has the new event inside List, but dosen't automatically shows it in widget until I reload page manually. I am also using streams to get the pile of data to update by itselfs and at the same time as data appeares in event.

I found only one way: it is add Stream.pireodic, but image which comes from event is flickering, but I don't need that behaviour. How can I solve this issue?

The main issue: the widget is not instantly updated and does not show data from the event

P.S Nothing except SignalR library dosen't work with websocket in my case

```
List wanted = [];

  Future<List?> fetchWantedFixation() async {
    final httpConnectionOptions = HttpConnectionOptions(
        accessTokenFactory: () => SharedPreferenceService().loginWithToken(),
        skipNegotiation: true,
        transport: HttpTransportType.WebSockets);
    final hubConnection = HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl(
          'http://websockets/sockets',
          options: httpConnectionOptions,
        )
        .build();
    await hubConnection.start();
    String? wantedFixation;
    int? index;
    hubConnection.on('Wanted', (arguments) {
      Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 7))
          .then((value) => alarmplayer.StopAlarm());
      alarmplayer.Alarm(url: 'assets/wanted.mp3', volume: 0.25);
      wanted = arguments as List;
    });
    hubConnection.onclose(({error}) {
      throw Exception(error);
    });
    print(wanted);
    return wanted;
  }

// it makes image flickering, but the event are updating
  Stream<List> getEvent() async* {
    yield* Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 5), (_) {
      return wanted;
    }).asyncMap((event) async => event);
  }
```

Comment: Are you using a stream builder in your widget?

Comment: @Tayormi yes, I am using StreamBuilder in my widget and as it was said in docs, it should work well, but my widget dosen't update as new events come